# Will stroking a cat or dog reduce a human's stress levels?

Tags: stress

I know that animals are sometimes used to visit people in hospital or care homes for the elderly. There seems to be a real benefit for those people.

I've heard it said that stroking a pet can calm you down, relax you, perhaps even create better moods, and reduce stress levels.

Is there any scientific evidence that owning a pet, in your own home, will cause a reduction in the owner's stress levels?

Comment: Somewhat related: Stroking a dog resulted in raised immunoglobulin levels (helps fight off ilness) - Charnetski CJ, Riggers S, Brennan FX. Effect of petting a dog on immune system function. Psychology Report, 2004;95:1087-91.

Comment: See also answers to http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2681/does-having-a-pet-help-to-cure-your-depression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been proposed by way of many studies that pet ownership can cause both short- and long-term stress relief. [This study](http://hyper.ahajournals.org/content/38/4/815.long) actually found that pet ownership is more effective at managing stress-related high blood pressure than ACE inhibitors (a blood pressure medication). [Another study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12271103) found that pet owners have significantly lower heart rates and blood pressure and higher rates of stress recovery than their non-pet-owning counterparts. As a result, pet owners tend to be healthier as well. And stroking a pet, even one that is not your own, has been shown to lower stress levels, too.